# recorder.js to node to azure speaker recognition

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cognitive-services, voice-recognition, recorder.js

I have a browser app which records the user's voice through their microphone and exports to a WAV file using recorder.js. I think convert that to a data url and post it to node. I then try to send the audio to the Microsoft Azure Speaker Recognition API but I always get "Invalid Audio Format: Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header" back.

Is there a way to add a RIFF header or is there something about recorder.js or converting to and from base64 which removes these headers? Is there a way to add them back in?

The code:
INDEX.HTML

```
rec.exportWAV(function (blob) {
    var reader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        base64 = reader.result;
        console.log(base64)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/addVoiceToProfile',
            data: { userId: '', voiceId: "XXX-XXX", voice: base64, sampleRate: audioContext.sampleRate / 1000 },
            success: function (results) {
                console.log(results)
            }
        })
    }
})
```

NODE ROUTE:

```
app.post('/addVoiceToProfile', function(req, res){
    var voicedata = req.body.voice;
    var base64Data = voicedata.replace(/^data:([A-Za-z-+/]+);base64,/, '');
    addVoicesToProfile(base64Data, req.body.voiceId).then(function(results){
        res.send(results)
    })
})
```

addVoicesToProfile:

```
function addVoicesToProfile(voice, id, user){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var url = AzureParameters.endPoint+"/spid/v1.0/verificationProfiles/"+id+"/enroll";
        request({
            url:url,
            headers:{'Content-Type':'audio/wave', 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':AzureParameters.key},
            body: Buffer.from(voice, 'base64').toString('binary'),
            method: "POST",
            json: true
        }, function(err, response, body){
            if(err) return reject(err);
            return resolve(body)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: You miss encodeWAV from recorder.js https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/08e7abd99739be6946f19f6806ccb368138f2dd3/src/recorder.js#L155. You also have typo in `sanpleRate`

Comment: Thanks Nikolay - where do I do the encodeWav?

Comment: Nevermind, it is already done in recorderjs. Fix sanpleRate first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was actually the way the file was being sent. I don't know why it works if it is sent as a wav in the body of the post, not as data in the post, but here is my working code if it is helpful for anyone in the future:

html:

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143548/stream-audio-to-azure-speech-api-by-node-js-on-browser) for the html. it includes the encoding for the wav. The only change I made was, as the answer suggests, I post to my server, not directly to the MS Azure service.

node route:

This took me a while as I couldn't get node to see the file I was sending. Also I am using bodyParser so the raw body of post requests is fiddled with before I see it. This is my route for the post request:

```
  app.post('/uploadAudio', function (req, res, next) {
    var data = new Buffer('');
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data = Buffer.concat([data, chunk]);
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        req.rawBody = data;
        next();
    });
  }, function (req, res) {
    addVoicesToProfile(req.rawBody)
  })
```

I hope this helps someone because both parts of this took me way too long to work out!